# Entity Framework Code first mapping without foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, code-first

I have two tables:

Requirement

- ID (int) PK
- ClientID (int)
- JobNumber (int)

Comment

- ID (int) PK
- Job_ID (int)
- Comment (varchar)

The tables don't have foreign keys and there's no possibility of adding any. I'm trying to map them in EF.  I have classes for each and I'm trying to define the relationship in fluent code to map the Comment.Job_ID to the Requirement.JobNumber.  A requirement can have many comments.  Requirement has a list of Comments and Comment has a Requirement property.

I have this mapping setup:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(c => c.Requirement)
                    .WithMany(s => s.Comments)
                    .HasForeignKey(f => f.Job_ID);
```

I'm stuck trying to get Comment.Job_ID to map to Requirement.JobNumber.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible. With Entity Framework the entity that the `Comment.Requirement` navigation property is refering to is generally identified by the (primary) key property in `Requirement`, i.e. by `ID`. There is no mapping option to define that the target property is anything else than the key property - like `JobNumber` or another non-key property.

I could only imagine that you could "fake" the primary key property in the model to be `JobNumber` instead of `ID` (given that `JobNumber` is unique in the `Requirement` table):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Requirement>().HasKey(r => r.JobNumber);
```

I don't know if that could have other unwished side effects. (For sure it doesn't work if `JobNumber` is *not* unique because EF wouldn't allow to have more than one entity with the same key attached to a context and updates/deletes and so on wouldn't find the correct record in the database.) It feels wrong and hacky to me. I honestly wouldn't even try that, live with the fact that you don't have a real foreign key relationship in the database, forget the navigation properties `Requirement.Comments` and `Comment.Requirement` and use manual `join`s in LINQ to relate the table data/entities as I need them in a given situation.

Comment: Thanks.  That's very helpful.  Was starting to feel like I was bending the rules a little too much.  Bad code smell :-)